# Migarting a flutter project to null safety fails with `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I'm trying to migrate my project to null-safety but the process crashes right after compiling instrumentation information step. The error I keep getting is not really helpful and doesn't point me to where the issue is taking place.

Here's the error message:

```
RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0
#0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:254:60)
#1      CodeChecker._checkCompoundAssignment (package:analyzer/src/task/strong/checker.dart:565:60)
#2      CodeChecker.visitAssignmentExpression (package:analyzer/src/task/strong/checker.dart:194:7)
#3      AssignmentExpressionImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:711:15)
#4      ExpressionStatementImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:3602:17)
#5      RecursiveAstVisitor.visitExpressionStatement (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:843:10)
#6      ExpressionStatementImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:3598:50)
#7      NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7517:20)
#8      BlockImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1069:17)
#9      RecursiveAstVisitor.visitBlock (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:675:10)
#10     BlockImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1065:50)
#11     WhileStatementImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:10630:11)
#12     CodeChecker.visitWhileStatement (package:analyzer/src/task/strong/checker.dart:532:10)
#13     WhileStatementImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:10625:50)
#14     NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7517:20)
#15     BlockImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1069:17)
#16     RecursiveAstVisitor.visitBlock (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:675:10)
#17     BlockImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1065:50)
#18     BlockFunctionBodyImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1024:12)
#19     RecursiveAstVisitor.visitBlockFunctionBody (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:681:10)
#20     BlockFunctionBodyImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1020:50)
#21     MethodDeclarationImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6951:11)
#22     RecursiveAstVisitor.visitMethodDeclaration (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:1071:10)
#23     MethodDeclarationImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:6942:50)
#24     NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7517:20)
#25     ClassDeclarationImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1544:13)
#26     RecursiveAstVisitor.visitClassDeclaration (package:analyzer/dart/ast/visitor.dart:711:10)
#27     ClassDeclarationImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:1514:50)
#28     NodeListImpl.accept (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:7517:20)
#29     CompilationUnitImpl.visitChildren (package:analyzer/src/dart/ast/ast.dart:2112:21)
#30     CodeChecker.visitCompilationUnit (package:analyzer/src/task/strong/checker.dart:230:10)
#31     LibraryAnalyzer._computeVerifyErrors (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:384:13)
#32     LibraryAnalyzer.analyzeSync.<anonymous closure> (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:141:7)
#33     _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:397:8)
#34     LibraryAnalyzer.analyzeSync (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:140:11)
#35     LibraryAnalyzer.analyze (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/library_analyzer.dart:104:12)
#36     AnalysisDriver._computeResolvedLibrary.<anonymous closure> (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1405:65)
#37     PerformanceLog.run (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/performance_logger.dart:32:15)
#38     AnalysisDriver._computeResolvedLibrary (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:1391:20)
#39     AnalysisDriver.performWork (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:970:22)
#40     AnalysisDriverScheduler._run (package:analyzer/src/dart/analysis/driver.dart:2006:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

And here's my Flutter doctor output:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, 2.3.0-24.1.pre, on macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.56.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Any information on how to solve the problem would be appreciated

Comment: Do you get the issue this issue on the **stable channel** as well?

Comment: @RohanThacker No, It worked when I switched to the stable channel. It doesn't work on master, beta and dev channels. Thank you!

Comment: Please [file an issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues).

Comment: @jamesdlin [I did](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46569)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved when I switched to the stable channel. However, this issue is reproducible on all the other flutter channels at the time of writing.

Comment: Open an issue on GitHub

Comment: @OMiShah I already have [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/46569)

Comment: The issue appears to be happening on latest stable: 2.5.2.  I got around the error by specifying the latest sdk version (2.14.0), but while the analysis tool successfully completed, the migration analysis results were not very useful, since the comp was based on a null safe sdk version.  The best I got was a nice long list of errors pointing to what things should be migrated.